# how to implement this process in wxpython?

Tags: events, wxpython

in wxpython, is there a event that can occur when one of the function of the panel or frame is called? thanks; for example, `self.Bind(wx.EVT_Onfunctioncalled, self.OnDoSomething)`

Well, I have to changed this question to a more specific one as follows:

I mean, well, the following process: I click on the menu "file" on the main window (as most GUI application looks), then "open", then a file directory dialog pops up, then I select a file, then I click "okay" on that dialog, then, I want that this file's name would appear on the listctrl on this main window, displaying which file I had select

Comment: AFAIK no. What are you trying to achieve? maybe there is another way...

Comment: @volting: thank you! I tried your code and it worked! and I have figured out my errors. the main difference is that the listctrl is a instance and it has a self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, ...), so when the key is pressed, it will respond and do some changes. what I tried to do is to show the names of files into the listctrl when I click on the "ok" button on the pop-up dialog

Comment: for this purpose, I instancialized a frame, well, it is a different instance from the original one, i.e.: the first one is <wx._controls.ListCtrl; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxPyListCtrl *' at 0x37039f0> >, and the second one is <wx._controls.ListCtrl; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxPyListCtrl *' at 0x37bfcb8> >, that's why the listctrl do not change

Comment: @volting: is there a way for implementing my work? i.e. display the name of the file into the listctrl on the main window after the user chose it for subsequent analysis, or after the whole analysis process. thanks

Comment: So you were adding the items to another list?(I not sure I understand). Anyway if I have answered that question then you should mark it as accepted (and vote me up), you even get some points for that :D –

Comment: With regard to your last comment, when you say display do you mean add? Im not sure I understand what you want to do!

Comment: yeah, I was wrong in doing that. hahahaha, I tried, but it told me that my reputation score was not high enough to vote :(, I wish I could. well, could you help me with this please, many thanks

Comment: If you still have a problem with adding items to your list then please update your original question with a runnable example of the problem, then maybe I can help, thanks

Comment: Well you can still click the little tick to accept the answer if it solves your problem that is :P

Comment: @ I mean, well, the following process: I click on the menu "file" on the main window (as most GUI application looks), then "open", then a file directory dialog pops up, then I select a file, then I click "okay" on that dialog, then, I want that this file's name would appear on the listctrl on this main window, displaying which file I had select

Comment: Ok got it, you should change the title and content your (this) question match this... Ill add a runnable example that should do what you want as soon as I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a runnable example that does what you want.

```
import wx

class ListTest(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, size=(380, 230))          
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        #Create a list                
        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT) 
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'File-path', width=140)

        #Do the layout
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(self.list, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

        #Create Menu
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        file = wx.Menu()
        self.loadFile = wx.MenuItem(file, -1, '&Open\tCtrl+L', 'Open a file')
        file.AppendItem(self.loadFile)
        menubar.Append(file, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_openFile)


    def on_openFile(self, evt):
        loadFileDlg = wx.FileDialog(
            self, message="Open File",
            defaultDir="",
            defaultFile="",
            style=wx.OPEN | wx.CHANGE_DIR
            )
        #If the user clicked the open file button
        if loadFileDlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:          
            #Get the file path
            path = loadFileDlg.GetPath()
        loadFileDlg.Destroy()

        #Call your file analysis method or whatever here

        #Create a message dialog 
        fileAnalysedDlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "File Has Been Analysed", "File Has Been Analysed", wx.OK)   
        fileAnalysedDlg.ShowModal()
        fileAnalysedDlg.Destroy()

        #Add filepath to list
        self.list.InsertStringItem(0, path)


app = wx.App()
ListTest(None, 'list test')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: @volting: thank you, is it possible to use this code like this: open the file for a analysis, when the analysis is done, a dialog pops up, then I click okay on that dialog, and then, the filename is showed into this listctrl??

Comment: @Serina: Sure why not? you just need to add code for a  message dialog and your code to analyse the file of course. What do you not know how to do?

Comment: @volting: Okay, I am not sure how to connect the event when I click the okay on the dialog to the display of filenames inside the listctrl, because these seem to be differnet things

Comment: Unlike things, such as key press, on enter window, etc, that can be directly binded to the listctrl panel or frame, when I click the okay on a message dialog, how could I expect the listctrl respond this? please, thanks

Comment: in particular, when these two parts are in different classes, i mean, the listctrl is in one class, whereas the anaylsis process is done in another class, so is the message dialog that tells me the process ends. then I click on the dialog, the file names display on the listctrl that is not of this class, well, I was confused...

Comment: Ok Iv updated my answer to include a `messageDialog`, execution is sequential so the dialog will only open after the file has been analysed. If file analysis takes a long time then you will need to take extra measures to prevent your GUI from freezing.

Comment: @volting: thank you so much! but what about the display of the filename was triggered in another class? it should not be binded to the panel as in your code, it happend when I click okay on the message dialog from another class

Comment: maybe I could send my codes to you then, is that alright?? please , thanks !

Comment: @Serina: I don't fully understand your problem. Why don't you try whatever it is you want to do, and if you then have difficulties ask a new question regarding this, provide a clear description of the problem and an example where possible, then myself or someone else will be able to help you better. Thanks